# Describe state space in reinforcement learning

Tags: r, agent, reinforcement-learning

I'm doing some reinforcement learning task where I have environment (consisting of grass, forest, dirt and water) and predator and prey. My prey is trying to keep away from predator for as long as possible, meanwhile consume water and grass to survive. I have 2 functions I must edit, `getStateDesc <- function(simData, preyId)` and `getReward <- function(oldstate, action, newstate)`. I already have some states and rewards implemented by default, and my state space is keeping record of `c(distance to predator, direction to predator, and if prey is on border)` states for qlearning algorithm. In reward function, my prey is penalized based od distance to predator and if it is trying to move on border. I now want to add state to check if my prey is in forest(so it can hide) for which I have implemented function isPreyInForest. I want to keep two states for this, if `isPreyInForest==TRUE => state<-1 if not state<-2` and based on this reward my agent later. Problem is that I cannot change dimension of state space (  `c(distance, direction, border)`, because when I try to add state to this ( `c(distance,direction,border,state)` and later in qlearning when I run the simulation with qlearning`(c(30, 4, 5,2), maxtrials=100)`
(notice that 30 here represent max distance from predator, 4 is direction so 4 max directions and 5 is border, where first 4 numbers are borders and 5 is when agent is not on border state) I have `Error in apply(Q, len + 1, "[", n) : dim(X) must have a positive length`. So any idea how to expand state space and give good argument to qlearning function?

Comment: It really looks like you should be using `list`s instead of vectors (`c`) so you can control what goes where.

Comment: It is defined that way, I was given functions, my task is to edit getStateDesc and getReward and to edit that qlearning and that's all.